# Editing memory in radare2

Tags: disassembly, memory, radare2

It sounds like a stupid question but I honestly can't find the answer... I've looked at https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/ and googled for hours but it still eludes me.

How do I modify the memory in radare2? I know if I want to modify a register value I can do:

```
dr eax = 0xA
```

But what about modifying a value in the stack or the heap at a specific address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the "write" section here https://github.com/pwntester/cheatsheets/blob/master/radare2.md or use `w?` to get help on the write commands.

Answer (score 2):

To write the string "foo" into the memory address 0xdeadbeef:

`w foo @ 0xdeadbeef`

To write the hex 0x41414141 to the memory address 0xdeadbeef:

`w \x41\x41\x41\x41 @ 0xdeadbeef`

I recommend also taking a look at the various options for writing using the command `w?`.